# Render another controller to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to render another controller to rails 2.3.2?

I was tried  below code.but not work.

app/controllers/vouchers

app/controllers/voucher_payments

### app/views/vouchers/show.html.erb

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test">test</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New Payment</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render :template => "/voucher_payments/new" %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### app/views/voucher_payments/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
```

can you help me?
thanks.

Comment: you are getting any template error?,is that the path relative to current directory?, where `voucher_payments` is located?

Comment: Try with full path `<%= render :template => "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/voucher_payments/new" %> `

Comment: You cannot render another controller, you can however render another view or another partial.

Comment: if i use   render template: "products/show" i got SyntaxError.

Comment: If you want to render another `view` in your `controller`, just write `render  'another'` (where another is the name of your view)

Comment: `voucher_payments` should be in, `app/views` and it should contain `new.html.erb` file. If yes. then the above should work. Can you give the folder structure?

Comment: if i use <%= render :template => 'voucher_payments/new' %> i didn't get an error.but if use <%= render :partial => 'voucher_payments/new' %> then got "Missing template voucher_payments/_new.erb in view path app/views" error

Comment: app/views/voucher_payments/new.html.erb

Comment: what is not working? any error in `rails console?`

Comment: Paste the whole code where you are trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a folder called `voucher_payments` in `app/views`

Now, in that `app/views/voucher_payments` you should have `new.html.erb`

`app/views/voucher_payments/new.html.erb`

So, now, [the document says](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) you can render the results of an action to a template in `app/views/voucher_payments` this way:

```
<%= render :template => 'voucher_payments/new' %>

<%= render "voucher_payments/new" %>

<%= render :partial => 'voucher_payments/new' %>
```

Comment: I tried above 3 options.but not work for me.thank for your answers

Comment: any error? restart the rails console? was the folder structure as above?

Comment: same structure.

Comment: here my code.    <div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New Payment</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render :template => "voucher_payments/new.html.erb" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: here only visible modal.not render part

Comment: test by taking `<h1>hello</h1>` in `new.html.erb` commenting the rest of code

Comment: is `voucher_payments` controller generated, or ,manual? , what is your controller name?

Comment: controller generated. "voucher_payments_controller.rb"

Comment: have you changed routes?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem, appending `.html` fixed it, try this

```
<%= render :template => '/voucher_payments/new.html' %>
```

Hope that works for you.